# Using strongly-typed configuration parameters in Windsor Installer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I've been cracking my head over [installing a Windsor container](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Installers&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) using a custom configuration object. It seems simple, but apparently there's something important I'm just not getting. I'll be grateful if you could help me fill this gap.

I have a configuration class:

```
class MyConfiguration
{
    int SomeIntValue;
    DateTime SomeDateValue;
    Action<string> SomeActionValue;
}
```

I want to pass these configuration values as constructor parameters into the registered implementations. I guess the registration should look something like:

```
public class MyInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
      container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>.ImplementedBy<Foo>
        .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("parameter1").Eq( INSERT VALUE HERE (?) );
   }
}
```

So how do I take these values and pass them into the installer? Should I use this `IConfigurationStore` parameter? If so, how do I fill it up and what do I do with it?

Besides, it seems like all the configurations objects can only store string values, so how can I pass values which are not strings (such as `DateTime`)?

Thanks and have a great weekend.

Comment: If you weren't using Castle Windsor, then where and how would you create an instance of MyConfiguration?

Comment: @Mark, MyConfiguration is a custom class, it has nothing to do with Castle. I just pass it as a parameter from the GUI layer to the initializer of the logic layer.

Comment: Then it's just a Component like any other. Let the container resolve it.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for this great idea, it may definitely solve half of the problem. As for the other half, I'm sorry, I just realized I mistyped the code in the question - edited it now. What I'm having difficulty with is passing a parameter to the constructor, not with setting a property (setting a property is easy). So if I understood correctly what you're saying, I should write something like `Resolve<MyConfiguration>().SomeDateValue` - right? And then, how do I take this date value and send it as a parameter to `Foo`'s constructor, given that `Parameter ... Eq()` only accepts a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the huge majority of cases you shouldn't have to explicitly register a constructor argument. The **auto-wiring** feature should be able to take care of that for you automatically. This will make your code less brittle and thus **more maintainable**.

So, the best you can do is simply to register MyConfiguration with the container. If this there's only a single registration of the type (the normal scenario), the container can unambiguously resolve any request for the type. Thus, if another class takes MyConfiguration as a constructor parameter, Castle Windsor will automatically match them for you. You don't need to specify this explicitly.

However, there are cases where you need to explicitly assign a particular parameter value. For those cases you can use ServiceOverrides. That might look something like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyConfiguration>().Named("myConfig"));
container.Register(Component
    .For<IFoo>()
    .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
    .ServiceOverrides(new { parameter1 = "myConfig" }));
```

If you need to assign a specific instance, you can instead use DependsOn:

```
var myConfig = new MyConfig();
container.Register(Component
    .For<IFoo>()
    .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
    .DependsOn(new { parameter1 = myConfig }));
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!!! How come hours of searching didn't help me find this? You're my hero.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to pass a type value, like an integer, string, enum etc then go with second option given by Mark..

```
int val = 23;
container.Register(Component
    .For<IFoo>()
    .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
    .DependsOn(new { parameter1 = val }));
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks.